# Xcode files in Red - but file still there

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been working on an Xcode project on my desktop, and I was trying to save it to GitHub, so I could access it on the road. I've saved it to GitHub before, without issues, and the local Desktop version was working fine. After saving it to GitHub, I tried downloading it on the laptop, to make sure everything was fine, and one file was in red. It doesn't look like it was saved or even exists. I get a "Build Input File can't be found" error.

I went back to the Desktop version - that file is there and everything works. I thought, maybe I messed up with GitHub, so I tried to save it to iCloud, and then emailed myself a zip copy - same thing. Every other version, but the desktop version, had that one missing file in red.

I've looked at other posts for those with similar problems, and all the answers seem to say the same thing - the file was moved or deleted; however, it is still there on my original desktop working version. Any thoughts as to what is going on or what I should do are welcome.

I'm working on XCode 13.1, on a Mac running iOS 12.1

Follow up - locked files:

As some of you suggested, the file could be locked. It didn't appear so, and I thought it unlikely, as I don't know how to lock them. I copied the one file over, added it, and it is running, however, I got this warning when I tried to save and close it:

[Locked file warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnunL.png)

I went through the steps to unlock it, and curiously, finder says it is not unlocked. [Not locked but I'm getting the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZuSt.png)

[Everyone has permission too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaEaa.png)

Any ideas as to why this might be? I'm stumped. I did try locking and then unlocking it, but no dice. I still get the error I don't have permission because it is a locked file.

Comment: Did you Try removing the file from finder, and add it in the project again ?

Comment: Did you check the permission on the file ?

Comment: Did you try to add it again to the project and what kind of file is it?

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani: Thanks I have not tried that. That didn't work, but I copied the one file, emailed it to myself, and manually added it in to the version with the missing file, and now, it's working. I realize this is a very poor, low tech solution, but, it'll get me by for now. Until I have to save my new changes.....then it happens again!

Comment: @PtitXav I did not check the permissions, and I am not actually sure how (I'm new at Xcode and I have been focused on the functionality not permissions. I found an article on where to look under Build Settings and Deployment and it doesn't look like there are any restrictions. I could be wrong, but as I haven't been over in this section before, I'm going to assume it is okay. Thank you for good suggestion!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: It's just a swift file, for a viewcontroller, no different than one of the other 10 I have (I'm new - not an efficient coder). the only thing different about this one is it was the last one that I added to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the file is not inside the project folder. This can easily happen with resources such as images and sound files that you copy to the project navigator. The project works fine but it has an external reference to the file. If the project folder is copied, eg zipped, the file is missing because it was not part of what was copied.

Comment: It appears to be in the file folder both in Xcode and when I check in Finder. There are no external references - the code in this file is some of the most pedestrian part of the project - and the only images are all in Assets, which are used by other files that work fine.

Outside of looking in Finder or the Xcode project, is there another way to tell if the file is not in the original?

Comment: My other guess would be that something is wrong with the file's path. In the original, select the file in the project navigator and switch to the File Inspector. Look at the path. Look at the Location pop-up and the Full Path pop-up. What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

This generally occurs when you moved or deleted that file within Finder.

So try to delete that file from your project in Xcode and then re-add that file to your project folder in Xcode. Then your file would be working fine.

Comment: Thanks - it wasn't moved or deleted, which is why I thought it so odd. I did follow your steps, copied the problem swift file, delete the old, and re-add it. It works fine on the local copy, but I get the same red- file missing issue as before. thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Did you try to push the latest code on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

first: get your file from the current full path and cony it to any location on your mac [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAuBM.jpg)
Second: delete the red file from Xcode
third: drag file from the new location to Xcode don't forget to check on copy if you needed :)

Comment: Thanks @sayed - I tried that, and the subsequent sharing to GitHub has the same results - that one file is missing. I did, however, copy the one file, email it to my laptop, and followed your steps, and it does work. Very low tech but it works.

I'm not sure what will happen next with the next updates, but I'll deal with that later. Thanks for your suggestions and advice.